# python scripting for android

Tags: android, python, eclipse, pydev, sl4a

I am trying to use eclipse and sl4a to create an android app for my tablet. I am following the procedure mentioned in this blog.

http://jokar-johnk.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-make-android-app-with-sl4a.html

1. I have my python scripts already compiled.
2. I need to make a '.apk' file using these python scripts, such that when I run the app in android, it should do what it is supposed to.
3. To create the '.apk' file, I am using eclipse with pydev plugin.
4. I created a clone of sl4a repository and imported to eclipse.
5. When I am creating a new project for android app development, I am not sure where to import my python scripts and embed them such that, at last I have an executable '.apk' file.
6. When I create a new project in eclipse, I see couple of folders like src, gen, res and several files under them. Where do I need to place my python scripts now? Do I need to create a separate folder under the project and directly import my python scripts or put them under src/gen/res?

Comment: try http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Development questions are off topic on Android.SE, as outlined in the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq). Please don't suggest that people post programming questions over there in the future.

Comment: Also, it is never a good idea to post the same question to multiple sites. If a question is a suitable for migration to another site, the moderators of those sites will do the migration, if not the question will stay where it is. Cross-posting is never the answer.

Comment: why don't you ask the blog author directly in that blog?

Answer (score 1):

As it says in that guide, you don't create a new project, you make a copy of the *ScriptForAndroidTemplate* template app, then:

> "Right click on your_script_name then open with text editor. Delete
>   the default script, replace it with your own and save. Then
>   Clean/Build/Refresh your project and run it."

And it should work!

Re-read (and follow) the tutorial if you're still stuck. Good luck!